# Bcoin node and testnet faucet

Tags: testnet, bcoin

I started `bcoin` in daemon mode (s I understand it is the same as full-node) with specifying `network: testnet`. As I understand it connected to the world-wide testnet. Now I want to get some test BTC. Running `bcoin wallet get` and getting this response:

```
{
  "network": "testnet",
  "wid": 1,
  "id": "primary",
  "initialized": true,
  "watchOnly": false,
  "accountDepth": 2,
  ..............
  "account": {
    "name": "default",
    "initialized": true,
    "witness": false,
    "watchOnly": false,
    "type": "pubkeyhash",
    "m": 1,
    "n": 1,
    ............
    "receiveAddress": "mz8iAEUBM6WueVgCzRsTht5wWjfyYxTF9c",
    "nestedAddress": null,
    "changeAddress": "mvSa7AnTQDTyWPBe6EbuB6KT5rLSrSgRP8",
    .............
    "keys": []
  }
}
```

So, as I see I have default account with wallet address `mz8iAEUBM6WueVgCzRsTht5wWjfyYxTF9c`. Then I am going to any testnet faucet (for instance https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet) and putting this address. After a while I see nothing on my balance: `bcoin wallet get`

```
{
  "wid": 1,
  "id": "primary",
  "account": -1,
  "unconfirmed": 0,
  "confirmed": 0
}
```

My question is: how to acquire testnet BTC for dev purposes?

Comment: is your node fully synced?

Comment: @tuxcanfly yes, it is synced finally and I see some btc on the balance but wondering why some amount still in "unconfirmed" state.